# How to append long tables into one master sheet (not consolidating)

Tags: excel

I've got about 10 sheets all with identical columns but varying numbers of rows (up to 1000 per sheet). Different people populate the sheets (and sometimes mess up the formatting unintentionally).

I'd like a way to pull all of the data into one master sheet, such that it grabs data from sheet 1, A1:H1000 and puts it in master sheet, A1:H1000, then grabs data from Sheet 2, A1:H1000 and puts it in master sheet, A1001:H2001

And so on. (So I can put filters/pivot tables on the master sheet and see everything in the system without having to manually grab data from each sheet - which get longer daily.)

I've tried defining ranges as tables, and can get it to do maybe 3 of the sheets but relies on the people populating the sheets being careful and it seems to get overloaded.

Is there a simple way?

TL;dr How do you automatically stack rows from sheets A and B on top of each other in sheet C?

Thanks!

Comment: Are the 10 sheets in a row? like Sheet1 to Sheet10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the sheets are ordered consecutively in the Workbook (say from indexes 1 to 10), you can use a simple loop:

```
Sub combine()

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim startRow As Long: startRow = 1
    Dim endRow As Long: endRow = 1000

    ' enter master sheet name below
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("master sheet name")

        ' setup the start & end indexes below
        For i = 1 To 10
            .Range(.Cells(startRow, "A"), .Cells(endRow, "H")).Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Range("A1:H1000").Value
            startRow = startRow + 1000
            endRow = endRow + 1000
        Next
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Kubie! The sheets are consecutive so would expect this to work; running this seems to do something (takes a while to process) but then there's nothing in the "master" sheet.

I've edited the "master sheet name", but nothing else. Do I need to be more specific in the VBA to tell it which sheets to look for?

Comment: what index do your data sheets start at? @JDoe, also just added `.Value` after the 2 ranges... should work now